# F#: Implement an inline method (On Inteface) to avoid using a real type

Tags: f#, inline

I'm trying to see if inline can be applied to an implemented method so that the specific type coming in doesn't have to be spelled out.  I've done this with one off (Not inherited/implemented) methods, but trying to also do using an interface.

```
type public IBookInteraction = 
  abstract inline CreateBook : 'a -> MethodResult<BasicBookModel>


type public BookInteraction(?userInteraction) =

  interface IBookInteraction with

  member inline x.CreateBook(bookModel) =
    let userId = (^a : (member UserId : Int32 with get) (bookModel))

    MethodResult<BasicBookModel>()
```

I'm guessing there's a way to do this, but it doesn't work with a generic operator(?) in the interface method signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to have abstract inline methods.  Even if you could, your code wouldn't work, because your interface definition promises that users can call it with any `'a`, but your implementation places a static member constraint on `'a` - in a hypothetical world where F# supported abstract inline methods, the declaration of the method on the interface would also need to include the constraint.

In any case, to see why it's not possible for F# to support abstract inline methods, consider what `inline` means: the code that you write to implement the method will be essentially copied and pasted into the call site.  However, with an abstract method, you don't know the concrete type that is defining the implementation of the method, so there's no way to figure out at compile time what code you're supposed to be inlining!

Comment: Yes, _abstract inline methods_ are definitely a nonsense. Just to add some more information - it is however quite useful to write _static inline methods_. This works, because the compiler exactly knows which method you're calling and so it can be inlined. Maybe that's a reason why the syntax allows it (although the compiler should still say that that's nonsense). See for example: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx

Comment: @Tomas - yes, absolutely.  Even instance inline methods make sense as long as they are non-virtual.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct answer is interface implementations may not be inlined. I'm not sure why it's allowed in the interface definition.